# Allow domain users to access content of a server not on the domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, network-share

Hopefully I will explain this correctly...

- We have a LAN with a domain controller and a number of application and database servers but due to our limited internet connection (bonded ADSL :( )
- As a result, we have a server in a data centre which will allow us to tranfer files from it must fast :D  It is connected using a VPN connection so accessing it with the local credentials is not a problem

Great, that was the easy!  Now, I have an application that I want to send and recieve files on demand.

So, currently I have

Server1.domain.local serving the application and providing the storage for the files

I now want

Server1.domain.local serving the application
server2.in.a.remote.localtion serving the storage

But as server 2 is not on the domain, a domain user cannot access it.

Oh, I should point out server 1 is running 2003 R2 and server 2 is running 2008 R2.  I cannot connect server2 to the domain as it is running over a VPN link and has an "Internet" IP.

I should also point out the application points to a network share, so working with a network share would make it 10 million times easier for that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I have added the machine to the domain now - I added the ip and hostname of the domain controller in the hosts file  and used the fqn of the network domain and it worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

If server2 is in its own domain (or could be made to be) you could assign it a one-way trust relationship, allowing server1 to automatically map drives to server2. Is that what you're after?

Comment: No, server 2 doesn't have it's own domain - I would set it up so it does but that machine has limited resources...  Is there no way that I could have server2 use groups from the domain, without connecting it to the domain.  Could I use AD Lightweight Directory Servies?

Comment: @Matt actually no you couldn't do that.  AD LDS isn't for NTLM or Kerberos authentication, it's for generic LDAP (like OpenLDAP) and a few Microsoft apps that use it to store data.  Also you can't have Windows using domain resources without it being in a domain itself (either the same domain or a trusted domain).